# Using Important Trees in Predict Command Using R

Tags: r, machine-learning, computer-vision, classification

I am using a data with 120 Features/Variables and 400 observations using R. After running RF and observing important trees, I came to know that I have only 10-15 very important trees. The final prediction (X1_Pred) of the validation data provides only 60% score. However, if I manually consider only first 40 Features/Variables, the score gets increased to 73%. I know how to find the important trees, but I don't know to use these important trees in predict command to increase my score. Code is provided. Please help resolve my problem.

```
    library(randomForest)
    library(e1071)
    library(caret)
    #library(ROCR)

    setwd("------")
    data <- read.csv(file="Corr_Table_All3.csv",header = T)

    # Now divide the data in Training (60%)/Validation(40%) parts
    sample.ind <- sample(2, nrow(data), replace = T, prob = c(0.6,0.4))  # It creates a vector of size nrow(data) with values 1 and 2.
    cross.train <- data[sample.ind==1,]
    cross.valid <- data[sample.ind==2,]

    # Now remove Last column (Labels) from the TRAINING data only
    varNames <- names(cross.train)
    varNames <- varNames[!varNames %in% c("X1")]

    # Now from formula type from TRAINING data only
    varNames1 <- paste(varNames, collapse = "+")
    rf.form <- as.formula(paste("X1", varNames1, sep = " ~ "))

    # Now apply formula to RF and see important Features/Variables/Predictors for TRAINING data only
    cross.rf <- randomForest(rf.form, cross.train, ntree=500, importance=T)
    var.imp <- data.frame(importance(cross.rf, type=2))
    var.imp$Variables <- row.names(var.imp)
    varImpPlot(cross.rf, sort = T, main="Variable Importance", n.var=40)

    # This is prediction stage and will be applied on VALIDATION data
    cross.valid$X1_Pred <- predict(cross.rf, cross.valid)
```